# How can I linearize the drag force without any constants terms?

Tags: classical-mechanics, linearization

How can I linearize the drag force at $V=V_{medium}$:

$F_d = \frac{1}{2}C_d.A.\rho .V(t)^2$
without any constant term? in the form:

$F_d=K_1V(t)+K_2$

K2 is the constant term and should be 0.

EDIT:
If I expand by Taylor I can get the linearization, but K2 will be not 0.
I need K2=0 to put the function in a space state for control theory. Do you have any ideas? I solved this kind of problems for other terms doing a linear transformation at the state variable (in the drag force case, this variable is V)

I'm kind stuck

Answer (score 0):

Let $k=C_d A \varrho$, which means that
$$F(V)=\frac{1}{2}kV^2$$
Using Taylor's theorem, we have that
$$F(V)\approx F(V_{medium})+F'(V_{medium})[V-V_{medium}]$$
I.e.
$$F(V) \approx \frac{1}{2}kV_{medium}^2+kV_{medium}[V-V_{medium}]$$

But the constant term won't be $0$. It happens because we can linearize it when the difference $V-V_{medium}$ is small, but in that case the constant is too big to neglect.

Comment: I had this problems, but I need K2=0 to put the function in a space state for control theory. Do you have any ideas? I solved this kind of problems for other terms doing a linear transformation at the state variable (in the drag force case, this variable is V).

Comment: @MatheusJosé What did you do in the other cases?

Comment: In other case, for instance, I had to linearize a function at $\alpha = \pi/4$, it was a function that depended of alpha and its second derivative. So I defined $\beta=\alpha -\pi/4$ and linearized at $\beta$ = 0. I get a function of bheta without any constant term.